# ASP.NET Identity Issue on Docker swarm cluster

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, docker, docker-swarm

I am trying to deploy my web app on a docker swarm cluster and as long as the # of replicas of the app are set to 1 everything works good.

I am using nginx proxy manager to access the swarm cluster and as soon as I increase the number of replicas of my app I seems like I loose my session and I have to re-authenticate, plus sometimes I get an error saying "too many redirects"

Partially solved using RedisCache with Data protection but not sure if this is best practice

Comment: This kind of scenarios usually handled by two ways: first one is externalize the session state like you do the other one is to write a routing rule based on a custom cookie once a request made to a server you make sure thr consecutive requests to go to the same server